# Connecting to host by SSH client in Linux by proxy

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, ubuntu-12.10

I am really struggling with this.

> My host (A) is behind a proxy/firewall (PF) and needs to connect to
>   host H.

The proxy has HTTP/FTP/SOCK proxy configured and I have no issue to configure in web browser, wget etc.

But when I use...

```
ssh H //to connect my host
```

I have no success to pass over the proxy. It seems to try to connect directly instead of going via the PF.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: So, are you trying to use an HTTP server to proxy SSH?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the docs for the ssh `ProxyCommand` option.  You can specify a command to run (for example, nc) to connect to a given host and port.  For example, adding this to your .ssh/config might work to traverse a SOCKS5 proxy:

```
ProxyCommand nc -x MY_PROXY_HOST:MY_PROXY_PORT %h %p
```

More detailed instructions are going to depend on your environment.

Comment: also add "-X connect" if you are going through an http(s) proxy instead of a SOCKS one.  ref: http://betterlogic.com/roger/2014/01/ssh-how-to-tunnel-through-an-http-proxy/

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to do it. You can use nc or try wrappers like corkscrew. I'll describe way with wrapeer:

Firstly install corkscrew by apt-get
Then you need to specify ProxyCommand in your **./ssh/config** file (replace example-proxy.com and 8080 with your proxy host and port):

```
Host *
  ProxyCommand corkscrew example-proxy.com 8080 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth
```

Your login credentials should be in ~/.ssh/proxyauth in format:

```
login:password
```

Comment: What does `%h %p` mean?

Comment: host and port, I presume.  What's the difference between nc vs. wrappers like corkscrew, here?